# Selenium FireFox 'This Connection is Untrusted'

Tags: python, firefox, https, selenium-webdriver

I have a question related to testing a website over https with an invalid certificate.  Can you please help? I am testing a website on the staging server. It requires https and it uses an invalid cert., which belongs to the production server.  So, when I go to the website, FireFox will bring up the 'This Connection is Untrusted page'.  I have managed to make firefox skip the page; however, if I don't run it using Selenium (the Python binding), it will show the 'Untrusted' page again.  So, I did more research and I found this:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UntrustedSSLCertificates
and the port:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=16168

However, it just doesn't work for me. The following is what I tried:

```
ff_profile.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", True)
ff_profile.set_preference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", True)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(ff_profile)
```

I am using:
FireFox 15.0.1
Selenium 2.22

Did I miss anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have just upgraded my Selenium to 2.26 and I am still reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def setUp(self):
        profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.default_preferences["webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer"] = 'false'
        profile.update_preferences()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will re-iterate what [user1411110](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411110/user1411110) said, with one change, False instead of 'false'. As string value is braking my webdriver Iceweasel instance.

```
 def setUp(self):
    profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.default_preferences["webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer"] = False
    profile.update_preferences()
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```